# Qt App doesn't load sql drivers when started by task scheduler

Tags: c++, qt, scheduled-tasks

I writed a small application and all Qt related dlls in same directory near the exe (sqldrivers folder too).

Problem: The app works when I start manually but when it started by task scheduler of windows gives "QSqlDatabase: driver not loaded, QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL ... blah blah" error.

Any idea?

Comment: I also tried to set  to "Path" system environment variable the app directory, but nothing changed...

Comment: Do you have qt.conf in that directory?

Comment: I tried to create qt.conf but It didn't work. Maybe I couldn't prepare it correctly, I don't know. I shared my alternative solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding path to the Path environment variable, realised that if I call myapp.exe in any other directory on command prompt it doesn't load the drivers, but if I change command prompt directory to the exe's path it works.

So I found an alternative solution as creating following bat file which I call with scheduler and it works.

```
@echo off
d:
cd MyAppPath
start "" "D:\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe"
exit
```

BTW don't forget to add the path to ["Path"] enviroment like "....;D:\MyAppPath"

Thanks for replies.

Comment: What? The scheduler doesn't change to the directory by itself? That's weird. Maybe there are some scheduler task settings that can change the dir? And on a side note, since you are starting a BAT anyway, you could set PATH just right there and leave the system settings alone, but that's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the libraries the Qt SQL driver plugins depend on (e.g. `libmysql.dll`) are in PATH, too.

Otherwise Qt can't `dlopen` any of the Qt plugins b/c dependencies are not satisfied.

PS: Check additional dependencies of the plugins in `sqldrivers/` with Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: libmysql.dll was alredy in there. I solved and shared my alternative solution. Thank you.